# Configuring camera for B+

Tags: camera, pi-b+

Okay, I've enabled the camera interface from the raspi-config menu, I've rebooted, and I've run vcgencmd get_camera.  It says that I have a camera supported, but it isn't detecting any.  The ribbon cable appears in tact, it is solidly connected, there is no damage to it or the terminals.  If there is supposed to be a light on the camera when it is plugged in, I do not see one.  Can anyone think of a hardware or software issue that would prevent the camera from being detected?

Using the Pi B+ V1.2 with [this camera](https://www.sainsmart.com/infrared-night-vision-surveillance-camera-2x-infrared-light-for-raspberry-pi.html?___store=en&nosto=nosto-recommendations)

EDIT: Is there any way for me to test the software or either piece of hardware to see if that's where the problem exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So before you guys start shouting at me, just remember that I have literally 0 experience with this stuff.  I accidentally figured it out, and it's a problem that there's no documentation for because it's a total noob problem.  Okay, you ready for the solution?

> Plug in the camera before booting the Pi...

....So uhhh.... ta-daaa?  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the RPi firmware recently? That's not an official RPi camera, and support may have been added since you last updated it. If you're running raspbian, doing an update (e.g. `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`) will update to the latest stable firmware.

Comment: I've already updated and upgraded it, yes.

Comment: What OS are you using on the RPi?

Comment: Raspbian from the NOOBS zip file.  I have 0 experience with using a Pi, so I picked the most basic thing.

Comment: Can you determine if it's "raspbian jessie", or perhaps "raspbian wheezy"?

Comment: Pretty sure it's jessie.  I saw that come up a lot during the update and upgrade

Comment: My monitor died about 40 minutes ago, so I'm now headless

Comment: You're having a rough go of it. I'd check with sainsmart support (looks like email only) for troubleshooting tips. Can you still get onto the RPi via ssh?

Comment: Been trying to.  Just had to install Putty, but I don't know the address, so I'm working on getting Zenmap to show it to me.  Already failed a list of easier methods to connect to it.  Working on requisitioning another monitor, but things are slow here at the lab.  Should have one before 5pm though.

Comment: Okay, I've concluded that I cannot SSH into it.  It looks like SSH is a menu item that defaults to off, and I haven't changed it, so I will not be able to access it that way.

Comment: If you can plug the SD card into a USB reader and access it from a desktop computer, create a file named `ssh` -- it can be empty -- in the `/boot` partition. Depending on your desktop, this may be the only readable partition on the card. That will enable ssh on startup. I assume you're using the wired Ethernet on the B+. If using wifi, you can create a `wpa_supplicant.conf` in the `/boot` partition to configure it as well.

Comment: So the funny thing about that is my SD reader doesn't work, and originally updated the micro-SD from home.  And yes, I'm using an Ethernet connection between the laptop and Pi

Comment: I think fate's got it in for you at this point. No display and no ability to modify the microSD card is going to be tough to work around.

Comment: Yeah.  Come tomorrow I'll have a display back and be able to continue troubleshooting.

Comment: Okay, monitor is back up.  This is definitely Jessie